# Как я могу расшифровать .ldb файлы?

Tags: c#, хеширование

Пытался открывать Access не получается, даже Max Payne Editor качал, не помогает. А  в интернете прогу нашёл, так она вообще пишет это:

```
LevelDB.LevelDBException (0x80004005): Corruption: CURRENT file does not end with newline
```

Comment: ... Прочитать то пробовали ошибку?

Comment: @ヒミコДа. Типо он не заканчивается новой линией. Но БД весит 900 КБ. Она точно не пустая.

Comment: Этот файл вообще откуда? От какой программы? Так-то расширение само по себе ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov от игры RockstarGames

Comment: Значит, Access и LevelDB совершенно не при чём. Ищите конкретный софт именно для файлов RockstarGames. Или сами изучайте его структуру.